# graphviz dot global defaults from within knitr?

Tags: r, graphviz, knitr

Is there any way to set global defaults like arrowsize for graphviz dot so that all graphs use them? I can't find anything about it in the documentation for the knitr dot engine (https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/057-engine-dot.Rmd).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Graphviz, so I have no idea. Anyway, the relevant source code in knitr is here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/engine.R This should make it more clear how knitr calls dot.